# Import ACM certificates to my local system

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-acm

I have a network load balancer which redirects my request to an instance which has mqtt hosted on it and I have a python script which sends the traffic to the NLB. This is currently working on tcp and I want to make this connection  secure so I have added a listener on port 8883 on my network load balancer and I have added acm certificate to it. Now I want to add this ACM certificate to my python script. How do I import this ACM certificate to my localsystem and add it to the python script?

Comment: Are you saying you are terminating TLS connections at the NLB and you want your client to trust the root CA for ACM certificates?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I import this ACM certificate to my localsystem and add it to the python script?

AWS ACM public SSL certificates **can't be exported**.

If you require to have control of a private key from your SSL cert, you need to get it from a third party, not from ACM. A popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/ which provides free SSL certificates.

Comment: How will I add these third party certificates to my network load balancer?

Comment: @AkshayJindal You can import them to ACM. ACM supports importing, but not exporting the certs.